# Select multiple countries on a map

Tags: javascript, forms, dictionary, multi-select

I need to provide a Web interface where users will be able to select countries on a map. This is the equivalent of checkboxes or a multi-select, just presented in a visual way.

I see two ways to tackle this and I am not sure where to start:

- either build the form elements, hide them, and bind them to a map
- or start from an interactive map, and store the clicked countries in a text field

Are there any examples or plugins that show how to achieve this? The specific requirement is to be able to select **multiple countries**, not just one.

Comment: Here's a start: http://notebook.kulchenko.com/maps/google-maps-api-examples

Comment: @MattBall thanks, but my question is specifically about multi-selects, not a general introduction to map APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this fairly easily with [Google's Data Visualization Geocharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart). Just initialize your Geochart. You need to pass in a `DataTable` for the chart to draw, so just pass in an empty `DataTable` without any row data.

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Countries']
    ]);

    var options = {
        //set any options you want to the chart
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Then listen for click events on the regions, using the `'regionClick'` event and you can append this to a list or handle the selected region data however you want. But this should provide a good starting point for country selections via a graphical map.

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', function(e) {
        //e.region gives you country code of selected country
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/9pMe4/)

Comment: +1 Thanks, but the core question is how to enable multi-select and bind this to a form.

Comment: My mistake, but that was not clearly outlined in your question. From what I understood you wanted a method that allows users to interact with a map to select multiple countries - and store these selections somewhere. I have provided a solution to do just that, but left it open for you to store the selected data however you like. You can capture them in an array, bind them to a textfield, etc. Which can be done in the event listener. Hope that helps.

Comment: Absolutely, and the demo was helpful. I was just hoping to see the full functionality already implemented in a js library or mvc framework. Maybe I am asking for too much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for how to do this, but I found this thread while trying to accomplish multiple country selections from a table. Basically, there are several existing fiddles on how to set everything else up, but where my code eventually differed is in the table selection handler. I set up a switch statement for each row of the table, and created a second (data2) variable for the chart to use:

```
       var selection = table.getSelection();
        switch(selection[0].row) {
    case 0:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['Argentina'],['Austraila'], ['Canada'], ['China'], ['India'], ['Japan'], ['New Zealand'], ['United Kingdom'], ['South Korea'], ['Saudi Arabia'], ['Singapore'], ['Taiwan'], ['United States']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;
    case 1:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['United States'], ['France'], ['Germany']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;
    case 2:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['Sweden'], ['Russia'], ['Brazil']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;
    case 3:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['Mexico'], ['Chile'], ['Iceland']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;
    case 4:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['Portugal'], ['Yemen'], ['Egypt']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;
    case 5:
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Countries'], ['Finland'], ['Belgium'], ['Ireland']]);
        Geochart.draw(data2, options);
        break;  
    default:
        alert('Row selection error!');
    }

});
```